# Java applet gets hung on web page whereas works fine on the other web page

Tags: java, applet

I am using a java applet in two web pages. In one of the web pages, it works fine whereas in the other web page, it just gets hung. In the 2nd webpage, I am passing two parameters to the applet (1st parameter -"path to a file", 2nd parameter- "string"). Its working fine in the applet viewer, but gets hung when embedded (But seems to have worked twice in some ten attempts) and the browser has to be killed. Any pointers on where to look for solution? (I have done signing jar and other required steps.)

Comment: how do we know with no information on what is being passed?

Comment: see https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free

Comment: @ifly6  1st parameter -"path to a file", 2nd parameter- "string"

Comment: are they in `char[]`? are they both `String`, or is it a `Path`? perhaps it is a `IntStream` from `String.chars()`. The type still matters, which is why the source code your wrote matters.

Comment: @ScaryWombat   Thank you for the info. I would definitely consider it for the next version development; but at this point, I doubt the feasibility to shift to a new technology given the time constraints

Comment: @ifly6 its provided as string. Actually it worked perfectly in 2 out of ten attempts.